# $POST and $GET to get value from dropdown

Tags: php, html, get

**a.html**

```
function load(str)
{   
    xhttp.open("GET","a.php?q="+str,true);
    xhttp.send();
    }           
}        
<select name = "select"  onchange ="load(this.value)">                   
  <option selected = "selected">Select a movie</option>                   
  <option value= "asc">Name in ascending order</option>
  <option value = "genre">Genre</option>                           
</select>
```

**a.php**

```
$asc = $_POST['asc'];
$genre = $_POST['genre'];
if (!empty($_GET[$asc])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies order by Name ASC";
} else if (!empty($_GET[$genre])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies order by Genre ASC";
}
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123"); 
$db_select = mysql_select_db('m',$db);
if ( ( $result = mysql_query( $sql, $db ) ) ) {
     echo $result;  
}
```

I want to select the value from dropdown button. For instance `asc`, and pass the value to `a.php ($asc = $_POST['asc'])`. How could I do that?

Comment: put it in a form, submit the form.. have you tried that? and btw, dont use the mysql driver, its bad, dangerous and deprecated.

Comment: @DevDonkey don't forget to mention that's removed in PHP7

Comment: yes, what @SuperDJ said :)

Comment: it returns  Undefined index: in $asc = $_POST['asc']; even though I have tried it in the form.

The question requires me to use mysql driver unfortunately

Comment: What Happened ? You didn't responded back @ikon ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <select class="movie" name="select">                   
        <option selected = "selected">Select a movie</option>                   
        <option value= "asc">Name in ascending order</option>
        <option value = "genre">Genre</option>                           
    </select>
        <div class="showMovie"></div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>   
        $('.movie').change(function(){
            var movieType= $('.movie').val();
            $.ajax({url:"a.php?movieType="+movieType,cache:false,success:function(result){
                $(".showMovie").html(result);
            }});
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**a.php**

```
<?php

$movieType = $_GET['movieType'];

if ($movieType == "asc") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies order by Name ASC";
} else if ($movieType == "genre") {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies order by Genre ASC";
}
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123"); 
$db_select = mysql_select_db('m',$db);
if (($result = mysql_query($sql, $db))) {
     while($movieName = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $movieName['Name']."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: it does not display any result :(

Comment: I did exactly like it, but still doesnt display anything

Comment: What is your column name for movie in table. Please tell @ikon

Comment: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>".$row['Name']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['Genre']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['Distributor']."</td>";
  echo "<td>".$row['Director']."</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
 }

Comment: Have you used `<div class="showMovie"></div>` in your page as i wrote below `<select>` dropdown & check `$(".showMovie").html(result);` is written or not in `ajax` @ikon

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I did follow your instructions. Unfortunately, no result is shown.

Comment: @ikon : *Glad To Hear* Keep Coding.

Answer (score 0):

with your JS function, you send it via a "get" method.
so you have your value into `$_GET['q']` ...

If you want to do a POST request, use a form, or an XmlHttp function:

```
function load(obj)
{
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlxttp.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200)
        {
            //called when xmlhttp event occurs, here when we receive the response
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseText); //Print the response into the console
        }
    }

    xmlhttp.open("POST", "a.php");
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'); //we send it as form
    xmlhttp.send(obj.value + "=" + encodeURICompopent(obj.innerHTML));
}
```

And call load(this) instead of load(this.value)

In php, to check is value is sent, just use isset:

```
if (isset($_POST['asc'])) //do something;
```

But I dislike this way to send values, it is deprecated: request parameters names should be static....

Answer (score 0):

**a.html**

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    $('#select_name').on('change', function() {
        var str = $(this).val();

        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",  
                url: "a.php",  
                data: { q:str},
                success: function(theResponse) {

                    // Output from ajaxpage.php
                    alert(theResponse); // comment this

                    }  
            });
    });
});                 
</script>

<select name = "select_name" id = "select_name">                   
  <option selected = "selected">Select a movie</option>                   
  <option value= "asc">Name in ascending order</option>
  <option value = "genre">Genre</option>                           
</select>
```

**a.php**

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123"); 
$db_select = mysql_select_db('m',$db);

$q   = isset($_POST['q']) ? $_POST['q'] : '';

if ($q == 'asc') 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies order by Name ASC";
} 
else if ($q == 'genre') 
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM movies order by Genre ASC";
}
else
{
    echo 'Nothing';exit();
}

$qry = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($qry) > 0)
{
$result = mysql_fetch_object($sql)  ;
echo $result;  
}
?>
```